Firestore documents caching in Firebase IOS SDK
I have read in the documentation that Firebase SDK automatically deletes least used documents from the cache. I am having a problem predicting what would happen in my following situation:
In my Home page, I have favorite subjects and all subjects.
favorite subjects are always fetched since it is always displayed.
all subjects are only fetched when user goes to the page.
I get those favorited subjects by locally saving document ids of favorited subjects as an array of string.
I then retrieve them from cache using:
let subjectsIds = userDefaults.object(forKey: subjectsKey) as? [String]
let query = db.firestore.subjects.whereField(FieldPath.documentID(), in: subjectsIds)
    

To save bandwidth, subjects document contains last_updated field of type Timestamp.
I first fetch all subjects in cache, then I get the greatest value of last_updated.
Then I get updated documents from server using:
let date = getGreatestLastUpdated()
let query = db.firestore.subjects.whereField("last_updated", isGreaterThan: date)

I am worried in the case the user does not navigate to all subjects page for a long time, causing all subjects in cache to get deleted except the favorited subjects since they are always fetched. This will cause subjects who has not been updated after the favorited subjects to not be retrieved from server using my method. Is this how cache deletion works in Firebase IOS SDK?

There is nothing about your first code sample that queries the cache specifically.  By default, all queries go to the server when the app is online, and the cache is only used when the app is offline.  I suggest reviewing the documentation about offline persistence to better understand its behavior.

The Firestore SDK manages the offline persistence cache for you.  You can't control when documents are evicted from the cache, so it's entirely possible that you will end up with no documents from a "all subjects".  The documentation states (emphasis mine):

When persistence is enabled, Cloud Firestore caches every document received from the backend for offline access. Cloud Firestore sets a default threshold for cache size. After exceeding the default, Cloud Firestore periodically attempts to clean up older, unused documents.

You don't get to choose which documents are removed. When the cache is cleaned up. It's based entirely on the frequency of use of all cached documents.
You should consider:

Increasing the cache size to reduce the chance of important documents being removed.
Creating your own cache of important documents so that nothing important become unavailable when it's needed.

